# input printing Traceback Error

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i'm trying to get user input, and print it on the screen, my code is

```
print("What is your name")
y = input("")
print(y)
```

When ever I put a number it prints, but when i type in a name for example Mike i get the error of,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F", line 10, in <module>
y = input("")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Mike' is not defined
```

I'm using Pycharm to write and run the program.

Comment: You are using Python 2.7, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Use `raw_input` as it seems that you are using python 2